# Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions) error in Python

Tags: python, gpt-3, chatgpt-api

I have a tts Python program that interprets speech-to-text data, and after that it asks this prompt to the GPT davinci-003 API and answers back, but I just switched to GPT 3.5 turbo, and it doesn't work because of the *Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions)* error.

I tried checking the model endpoint compatibility web page and also tried asking [GPT-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3) and [GPT-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-4). I didn’t get any answer.

I checked [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) as well, but I didn’t find anything. Also, I checked Stack Overflow, but I didn’t find anything either.

This is the API endpoint URL or at least the one I tried.

[image]

My current GPT-3.5 turbo engine code:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76001873/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using *engines* is deprecated](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/engines). Use *model* instead.

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=messages,
    max_tokens=1000,
    n=1,
    temperature=0.3,
)
```